# checking if range of array keys is number

Tags: php

I'm looking to loop through a an array and check whether the values are numbers.

for example

*$rowdata is a mutltidimensional array*

```
if (!is_int($rowData[0][0]||$rowData[0][1]||$rowData[0][2]) {
echo the value which is not a integer
```

}

Just for information, i already have the loop working it how i could achieve the above

Comment: Well, you know you need a loop, so why dont you give it a try and post back here if you get stuck. Questions simply asking for code are not well received here on stackoverflow

Comment: I already have the loop working its just understanding how the to achieve the above

Comment: OK rob, well please edit your question to show the loop code you currently have, and explain whats not working with it

Comment: You forget to close the if statement parentheses if (!is_int($rowData[0][0]||$rowData[0][1]||$rowData[0][2])) your code is working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Your `if(!is_int($rowData[0][0]||$rowData[0][1]||$rowData[0][2]))` is wrong. you have to split the parameter up like this:

`if(!is_int($rowData[0][0]) || is_int_($rowData[0][1]) || is_int($rowData[0][2]))`

---

**Working dynamic solution here:**

use a nested foreach-loop

```
$rowData = array(array(1,2,"3"),array("asdf",1,"sadf"));

foreach($rowData as $key1=>$row1){
    foreach($row1 as $key2=>$row2){
        if(is_int($row2)){
            echo "\$rowData[$key1][$key2] is int".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
$rowData[0][0] is int
$rowData[0][1] is int
$rowData[1][1] is int
```

**[Snippet Example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88c75fba3e49e30be7c2bf28c472be972ab69b30)**

Answer (score 0):

For a single array, this is a simple method to confirm that all are ints:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4];
$allInt = array_reduce($a, function ($r, $i) { return $r && is_int($i); }, true);
```

So for your case:

```
if (!array_reduce($row[0], function ($r, $i) { return $r && is_int($i); }, true)) {
    // not all are integers
}
```

An alternative method, which also returns you the non-integer items:

```
array_filter($a, function ($i) { return !is_int($i); })
```

So:

```
if ($notInt = array_filter($row[0], function ($i) { return !is_int($i); })) {
    echo 'Not integers: ', join(', ', $notInt);
}
```